# Strange problem with blackberry Torch 9800 simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

When I start the torch 9800 simulator programmatically through fledge.exe, a pop up displays with licenese agreement, and it is always coming up at device startup, due to this I am unable to make TCP connection from simulator.

I tested above mentioned behavior in 4.7 simulator (9530), without pop up  at startup TCP connection working, with pop up window at device startup, unbale to make TCP connection. And an IOException is been thrown in this case.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of the license agreement pop up at device startup in torch 9800 simulator through programmatically or some how??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have "Reset NVRAM on startup" setting on. Turn it off in your IDE in "Memory" tab of simulator settings.

Or turn it off in appropriate xml. E.g. 9800.xml if you run `fledge.exe /app-param=JvmAlxConfigFile:9800.xml`